# Last help question of the day for this novice

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Thanks for all of the help in identifying parts to a tub of LEGO I received back in 2019 but have not looked at until yesterday because my daughter has started getting into LEGO. I am so thankful for this community since I am a novice. I took a look through the Sterilite tub of LEGO again today and pulled some more creations that I thought would be worth a try posting here. For what it is worth, I appear to have parts from the following sets: Lego City Ambulance Helicopter; T. Rex Transport; Republic Fighter Tank; Yodi's Jedi Starfighter; The Phantom; Hogwort's Whimping Willow; Minecraft The Waterfall Base; Jakku Quadjumper; Tie Striker; Jokerland; Piranha Attack; Hulk v. Red Hulk; Simpson's House; The Penguin Arctic Roller; Airport Cargo Plane; Nexo Knights 70320; The Batmobile; The Riddler Riddle Racer and City Ferry. Another user helped me identify portions of sets from Mighty Micros Wonder Woman v. Doomsday; Minecraft The Dungeon; Hoth Generator Attack; Mini Cooper S Rally and 2018 Mini John Cooper Works Buggy; Minecraft The Chicken Coop; and Mighty Micros Spider Man v. Green Goblin.  I doubt I have any complete sets at this point though. Does anyone recognize parts of any sets listed above or otherwise here, and which set? I saved what I thought was the hardest for last.  I don't even know how to describe the pictures.  Thanks so much!

1. [image: Picture 1]
2. [image: Picture 2]
3. [image: Picture 3]
4. [image: Picture 4]
5. [image: Picture 5]
6. [image: Picture 6]
7. [image: Picture 7]
8. [image: Picture 8 - a bunch of miscellaneous ones]

Answer (score 4):

**#1** was the hardest to find, I searched for sets with the [Black Engine, Large](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43121#T=C&C=11), eventually I found that [70905 The Batmobile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70905-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) contained all the parts in the image, although the engine isn't visible.
[image]

**#2** was a little easier, I searched by [Dark Bluish Grey Mudguard](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18974&idColor=85#T=C&C=85). Of the four sets, [75877 Mercedes-AMG GT3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75877-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) was the only match.
[image]

**#3** I cross-referenced the yellow slopes and the dark grey trap door frame to find [76078 Hulk vs. Red Hulk](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76078-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]

**#4**, **#5**, and **#6** all appear to be parts of [75178 Jakku Quadjumper](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75178-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), although the lime brick 1 x 1 round appears to be a colour substitution.
[image]

**#7** is the centre of [75971 Hanzo vs. Genji](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75971-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
As well as a tea cup from one of [these sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=38014&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Tea%20Cup&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C)
[image]

**#8** has the front of Hulks car from 76078, and parts from these sets:

The torso from one of the models of [31058 Mighty Dinosaurs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31058-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
Part of the carnivorous plant from [75904 Mystery Mansion](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75904-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
The Joker's hat from [76035 Jokerland](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76035-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
Catwoman's motorcycle wheel from [70902 Catwoman Catcycle Chase](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70902-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
One of the wings from [75129 Wookie Gunship](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75129-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
The ghost vacuum from [71242 Story Pack - Ghostbusters: Play the Complete Movie](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=71242-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]
Some of the detailing on the front and underside from [70911 The Penguin Arctic Roller](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70911-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
[image]
The large black leg is from one of the many [Star Wars buildable figures with black legs](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=21562&colorID=11&in=A)
[image]